# Refresh em PartialView perde referência JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um método JavaScript/Jquery que atualiza uma PartialView e dentro dela existe uma div com um `fadeToggle` associado.

JavaScript no Onload (para associar o FadeToggle) (Funciona)

```
$("#ComentarioAba").click(function () {
    $("#Comentario").fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Método JavaScript:

```
function ReloadComentarios() {
    $('#Comentarios').empty();
    $('#Comentarios').load(document.URL + ' #ComentarioAba');

    $("#ComentarioAba").click(function () {
        $("#Comentario").fadeToggle(500);
    });
}
```

Código HTML

```
<div id="Comentarios">
   <div id="ComentarioAba" class="col-md-12 mwTituloArea">
      <p>Comentários </p>
   </div>
   <div id="Comentario" class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 ">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Acontece que depois que o método `ReloadComentarios` é executado, o `fadeToggle` não funciona mais. Mesmo a associação sendo refeita dentro do próprio método.

Por quê isso ocorre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade não perde a referência.

Acontece que **o Load só atualiza a Div de ID** `#ComentarioAba` confomre a chamada:

```
$('#Comentarios').load(document.URL + ' #ComentarioAba');
```

Para corrigir foi preciso "aninhar" mais uma div e ficou assim:

```
<div id="Comentarios">
   <div id="ComentariosReload">
      <div id="ComentarioAba" class="col-md-12 mwTituloArea">
         <p>Comentários </p>
      </div>
      <div id="Comentario" class="col-md-12">
         <div class="col-md-12 ">
           ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

e depois atualizar o JavaScript para dar o Reload em `ComentariosReload`:

```
$('#Comentarios').load(document.URL + ' #ComentarioAba');
```

Portanto, a referência de JavaScript não estava se perdendo, o que se perdia era a Div que não era mais carregada/processada e por isso o Toogle não iria funcionar, já que a DIV não existia mais.